# python2.7: how to plot the value of the grid line of x-axis in the figure

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Hi I ploted two lines in a figure, the x-axis is the datetime from '2016-04-01' to '2017-03-31', the value showed on the grid line width is one month, namely 30 days, but I want to the grid line of width is 50 days. I mean that I want to show the date value of x-axis is: 2016-04-01, 2016-05-21,2016-07-10,2016-10-18,2016-12-07,2017-01-26,2017-03-17.

T

My code is following:

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


sn.set_style("darkgrid")
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
lst_predictions = list(predictions2)
len_predictions = len(lst_predictions)
plt.plot(lst_index, list(test_y2), label = 'actual')
plt.ylim(ymin=0) 
plt.ylim(ymax=140)  
plt.xlim([lst_index[0], lst_index[-1]])
plt.plot(lst_index, lst_predictions, label='pred')

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid(True)
```

Comment: It's rather difficult to get 50days spacings of the grid and to let the grid start on first of April. Is both a requirement?

Comment: The Apri 1st is the first date of  lst_index, just the first index is ok. Yes I want to get 50 days spacing of the grid.

Comment: I provided an answer below, even though I don't know how to meet both requirements at the same time. You may choose if having the first index marked and using monthly ticks or having the 50 days interval is more important to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DayLocator` to control the location of the ticks.

```
xloc = mdates.DayLocator(interval=50)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)
```

Usually you would use it in cases where you want to mark the 1st and 15th of each month or so. Since 50 days is more than a month, the location cannot be determined in terms of a month. You may still use the interval argument to space the ticks 50 days appart. However the starting point will be rather arbitrary.

Complete code:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

start_date = datetime.date(2016, 04, 01)
end_date   = datetime.date(2017, 07, 01)
date_list = [ start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days))]

values = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(len(date_list))-.5)+20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,4))

ax.plot(date_list, values, label = 'actual')

xloc = mdates.DayLocator(interval=50)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)

xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]